# How add() on set can work in such dictionary?

Tags: python

I struggle to understand the following code, how can add() apply to the set in the following dictionary:

```
for word in tokenize(name):
    index.setdefault(word, set()).add(char)
```

"add()" is method of set and not a method of dictionary. So how can it be that is adding values to the set in a dictionary?

how can the method .add(char) be

Comment: [What does `index.setdefault(word, set())` return?](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

Comment: `setdefault()` returns the value being added to the dictionary, not the dictionary.

Comment: ok so it returns a set to which I can add values. thanks lot!